# Possible to cause the cells to produce less/no chemicals?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, physiology

I have a question regarding cells producing chemicals, e.g. some metabolite, inside the body. Is it possible to inject something (at least theoretically possible, and maybe practically possible in the future) into the body to inactivate these chemicals (e.g. enzymatically), or inject something which makes the cells produce less/none of the chemicals?

Comment: Please define *killing a chemical*.

Comment: I just mean that I would like the chemicals to decay very fast so that it does not affect the traction force exerted by the cells any more.

Comment: Now I'm more confused than before...

Comment: Okay, but do you believe we can do something to increase the decay rate of the chemicals without killing the cells?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I tried to clarify your terminology in an edit - does that capture what you mean? Please feel free to further edit. And does that make things clearer for you, @GerardoFurtado?

Comment: It will depend on the metabolite, metabolic pathway and the cell of interest.

Comment: Okay. I am thinking about cancer cells distributed inside of a spherical collagen gel.

Comment: Basically all of pharmacology consists of something that can be injected, consumed, applied topically, etc to cause cells to produce more of something or less of something.